# Oauth Python twitter auth

Tags: python, oauth

```
import oauth2 as oauth

key = "xxxxx"
secret = "xxxxx"

request_token_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"

consumer = oauth.Consumer(key= key, secret= secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer)

resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")

print content
```

Once i have executed this script it works fine but what would be the best way to deal with the output it gives me.

The output is something like "xxxxxxxx&yyyyyyyyyy&zzzzzzzzz"

And i need to use the varaibles xxxx and yyyy how can i parse these and put them into variables?

Thanks
William

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output = content.split('&')
x = output[0]
y = output[1]
```

also check out Tweepy for Python interaction with Twitter.
https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy

Comment: Another option is [rauth](https://github.com/litl/rauth) see this [Twitter example](https://github.com/litl/rauth/blob/master/examples/twitter-timeline-cli.py).